# How to get a list of files to be downloaded using HttpClient or Commons VFS?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons-vfs

I would want to know if there any another way to get a list of files to be downloaded from HttpServer,other than parsing the response using HttpClient.

I would also like to know if Commonns VFS is a suitable alternative for this as I tried using VFS but was not able to obtain just the list of files. 
I checked an example for sftp in vfs, but was not able to implement it in Http.

Say i have this link `http://www.ibiblio.org/maven/maven/jars/` is there a way in either HttpClient or Common VFS to just obtain the list of jars. The download portion is easier.

Comment: As an alternative you can use JSoup.

Look at [that other message][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java

Answer (score 0):

For HttpClient, short answer is no.

If you still want to do it with HttpClient, then you'll first have to extract the jar links, then retrieve each one of them separately.

Comment: Thanks I so it's confirmed that I would need to try with VFS. any clue about that? When I tried with VFS also I could get only one jar at a time .

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can do that with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Look at [that other message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java)