# download a folder from the given url using java

Tags: java, file, io, awt

I am trying to copy a folder from server to local system but dont know how I have written the code to copy the file from server but confused to copy the complete folder .
For copying a file i am using the following code.

```
  BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
        {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (fout != null)
            fout.close();
    }
```

and its working properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of files/directories of an directory url in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple trick you can make this possible with http. First check when you open the url of a folder in browser, how the representation is. Generally it could be like bellow,

--back

--file1.mp3

--file2.doc

--some other file

--some other folder

If you see here everything is represented with hyperlinks. You have to **parse** those hyperlinks, and you can download files from each hyperlink provided. In case if any hyperlink represents another folder (sub folder), you have to do the same procedure I have stated above.

If you can parse the data properly, it is really easy to download whole folder.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP does not know about folders. Especially, there is no way to list all the URLs of the files that are in a "folder". So basically, what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Because it's an answer. It might not be the one that adesh singh likes to hear, but it's an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote folder is mounted on your file system, I recommend you the use of Apache Commons IO, [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

In the other hand, if your remote server has only a HTTP interface, you need to know the URLs of the files to be downloaded, unless the directory listing was allowed (which is not usual). [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) may be useful.