# How to list all files in directory from http server?

Tags: java, http

I would like to get a list of all files contained in a directory from http server using Android API having only server's URL. How can i achieve it?

By the way - I have the access to the server if there was anything needed to set up.

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with Android and everything to do with adding code to your server, please use more relevant tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java

Comment: Unless the server allows this or implements it, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a PHP-Script to scan all files on your server for example like that:

```
<?php
$directory = '/path/to/files';

if ( ! is_dir($directory)) {
    exit('Invalid diretory path');
}

$files = array();

foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
    $files[] = $file;
}

var_dump($files);  // YOU HAVE TO WRITE THE OUTPUT AS JSON OR XML
?>
```

With android you have to only call this script like:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

(To execute the asyncTask:

```
 new RequestTask().execute("URI to PHP Script");
```

)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I dont understand, the ASyncTask expects a URI and you write, that the PHP script has to be passed?