# how can i download only the file in server directory in android?

Tags: android, download, intentservice

**possible duplicate :**

[How to list all files in directory from http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417415/how-to-list-all-files-in-directory-from-http-server)

but in my case the server is not handled by me.so i cannot able to implement this answer.

In my application i need to download the file from the server in background intentservice and after download completion i show a different fragment for video,music and document file.

But i need to download only the files in whole directory in the public server.(without downloading the folder/directory).

**for example:**

```
String url = {http://www.mee.com/server/content/};
```

download all files in this directory without downloading sub-directory from server.

I tried some code to download multiple files from server with url and succeed in that. but now i need to download the files from directory without file path url.

Comment: any reason for downvote

Comment: reason for upvote? this guy don't know http basics ... there is no way to list files on server without script using plain http protocol ... also  [very strange vote pattern apr 7](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4898357/beginner?tab=reputation) looks like a serial upvote dor me