# Java http get list of subdirectories and files

Tags: java, http

I'm making a program that needs to scan some online directory and its subdirectories and automatically needs to download newly added files. The URL looks like this:
http://blahblah.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/blah/models/
And within the models folder new subfolders will be added. For example: a subfolder v25. In the subfolder will be several files that I need to download.
Doesn't sound to hard but I can't find a way to list all the subdirectories / files from an online directory?

Found solution here:
[How to get list of files/directories of an directory url in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java)
Looks like I was Googling with the wrong keywords.

Comment: First thing's first, is directory listing enabled for that folder?

Comment: Yes, but I found the solution already. Apparently it's not possible to do it straight like that. You need to download & parse the HTML first. Kinda strange that there is no nicer way.