# Get all the files that starts with a specific word from a URL using ANT

Tags: java, url, ant

I'm using the following task to get a specific file from a URL and install it on my local DIR:

```
<project name="MobileBanking" basedir="../">
    <target name="get">
        <get src="https://domain/dsprdamf1/mf/node1/logs/server11_mf/trace.log" dest="Local/Logs" usetimestamp="true" username="${USERNAME}" password="${PASSWORD}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

However, the problem is that I have multiple files that starts with word "trace" and I need to get them all to my local directory.

I've tried the following:

```
<get src="https://domain/dsprdamf1/mf/node1/logs/server11_mf/trace*" dest="Local/Logs" usetimestamp="true" username="${USERNAME}" password="${PASSWORD}"/>
```

and

```
<get src="https://domain/dsprdamf1/mf/node1/logs/server11_mf/*" dest="Local/Logs" usetimestamp="true" username="${USERNAME}" password="${PASSWORD}"/>
```

but none worked.

What should I use to get all the files that start with word "trace" from a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with URLs. The `get` task retrieves a file from *any* URL. In order to support pattern based forms of a URL input such as `basePath/trace*.html`, the task should query the URL `basePath` and parse the content HTML of the page to determine the list of HTML pages in this path, which is a thing tedious to do (if possible in the first place, see [How to get list of files/directories of an directory url in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java)). Try getting the content of the base URL, parse its result and see if you can get the list of all `trace*` files there (this may be a solution, but it is very ugly).

You can look at alternatives like the [`ftp`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) or [`scp`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) tasks which support nested `fileset` resources with `include` and `exclude` wildcard patterns. Unlike the `get` task, `ftp` works based on the FTP protocol which allows getting a list of files in a remote directory. However this requires services like the FTP server or SSH daemon to be available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you are right about this. I need to find another way to get all the nested files other than "get". Will check ftp or scp.